# If I let Google handle my emails for my domain, my Wordpress site won't send out emails anymore

Tags: domain, email-server, wordpress, gmail, google

Since I decided to let Google handle all my emails for my domain, while the domain is hosted on a 3rd party server, emails send out by a Wordpress installation no longer work.

My supposition is that since all email is being routed to Google, my specific account on that server for that domain is unable to send out emails.

I definitely wish to keep using google services for handling my emails since it comes with all the advantages connected to a Google account.

However I need my Wordpress installation to send out administrative emails.
I run my server with CPanel.

How to configure that specific account and/or Wordpress to keep it able to send out emails? I don't need people to answer these emails sent out from server (eventually I might set a reply-to-address perhaps)

thanks

Comment: Step one: work out why the e-mails aren't being sent.  Supposition is no good.  Use logs, bounces, strace, and potentially a debugger to work out why the e-mails aren't being sent.  Once you know that, if the solution isn't obvious, *then* ask a question about how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well configure your Wordpress installation to send emails via an email account of yours on the domain using SMTP Authentication.

This will result is emails being sent by Wordpress app through an email account and thereby preventing the default mail() function of PHP.

There could be many and the one I could find might not be the best so please search the Wordpress plugins site. But here is a plugin I could find which allows you to configure SMTP authentication in Wordpress.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Additionally, I would also suggest you have your web host check and make sure that your domain entry does not reside in the file /etc/localdomains. Since you've configured email to be on Google Servers/offshore, your domain entry should be in the file /etc/remotedomains.

Comment: thank you I just found out about that plugin (and a few similar ones)